# Is there a reason not to use one time objects over explicitly declared ones

Tags: .net, object

Lately I have been spending a lot of time ensuring that my objects all had names that would allow easy identification of their meaning. I have also discovered that you can use objects in a one time fashion like so:

```
_ProfileList = (New RegistryManager).GetAllProfiles()
```

As opposed to creating a named object.

Is there a reason not to do this when all you want is one time access to an object? If anyone knows the pro's and cons that would be great.

PS: It is VB.NET code but either it or C# will be fine if providing examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That *is* explicit - it just isn't stored in a variable (indeed, the *object* **never** has a "name" - only local variables/fields have names). If you don't need the object more than once, and it doesn't make the core more complicated, then there is no real disadvantage to this. Note that if the object is `IDisposable` or similar, you will want a local, i.e.

```
using(var manager = new RegistryManager()) {
     _ProfileList = manager.GetAllProfiles();
}
```

but other than that, it doesn't care. Indeed, if you **do** assign to a local and use it right away, I would expect any "release" build to remove the variable completely *anyway*, meaning that *once compiled* (in release)

```
var manager = new RegistryManager();
_ProfileList = manager .GetAllProfiles();
```

and

```
_ProfileList = (new RegistryManager()).GetAllProfiles();
```

are identical (my expectation).

Comment: Sweet, thanks for that, especially the little blurb about using a local with IDisposable.

Answer (score 1):

*Objects* don't have names - variables do.

It's absolutely fine to create an object and use it solely within another expression - although I'd argue that something like a `RegistryManager` sounds like it should be a dependency passed in, and *not* something created within the code like this. It'll make testing harder.

A better example of where this is fine would be `StringBuilder`:

```
string text = new StringBuilder().Append("Foo")
                                 .Append(name)
                                 .DoOtherAppending()
                                 .ToString();
```

Comment: I agree that it should be a dependency, unfortunately I don't get to decide the architecture (I'm a junior) so for now my 'Fancy Talk' about DI and testing goes unnoticed.